# Can I change the IPP "Sign in with Intuit" button size?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Per QBO's documentation here...

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0030_integrate_your_app/0030_signing_into_and_out_of_intuit_from_within_your_app/sign-in#AddSIButton

...I added the SSO login button via this code:

```
<ipp:login href="http://example.com/myapp/SendOpenIDRequest" type="vertical"></ipp:login>
```

This works; however, it loads a comically small login button. Looking into the css, the image loaded is:

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/button_signinwithintuit_horiz_small.png

[image: teeny tiny image]

So, using my super detective skills I changed the small to large and get this working image:

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/button_signinwithintuit_horiz_large.png

[image: hefty hefty hefty]

BUT, there doesn't appear to be any documented way to display large instead of small, and modifying it using my css is against QBO's guidelines.

Is there something I missed in the documentation or perhaps is documented elsewhere to use that larger image?

Comment: There is no doc available on this. It is expected to use SSO and C2QB wizards as is form. Thanks

Comment: @ManasMukherjee I'm not sure what you mean by "It is expected to use SSO and C2QB wizards as is form."

Comment: SSO implementation is a requirement if you want to publish your app in app.com. We(from IPP) don't recommend developers to change these standard wizards. That's why there is no docs which shows how to modify these wizards.

Comment: Manas is right. You cannot made any modifications to the widgets provided by Intuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following CSS will display the large icon instead of the small. Ran into the same issue myself.

```
.intuitPlatformLoginButtonHorizontal
{
background: url(https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/button_signinwithintuit_horiz_large.png) no-repeat 0 0;
width: 200px;
height: 43px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SSO implementation is a requirement if you want to publish your app in app.com. IPP doesn't recommend developers to change these standard wizards. That's why there is no docs which shows how to modify these wizards.

Thanks

Comment: Can we get this "Sign in with Intuit" button in french language? I am localizing application on French version.